# Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits _{k=3}^{n} \frac{1}{3^{k-2}}\right)=\frac 1 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits _{k=3}^{n} \frac{1}{3^{k-2}}\right)=\frac 1 2$?

I've tried to group the partial sums in order to come to a conclusion, but nothing really worked. I've tried to substract partial sums but just ended up getting the series itself as the result of it.

$S_n:= \frac 1 {3^1} +\frac 1  {3^2}+\dots+\frac 1  {3^{n-2}}$, $3S_n:=1+\frac 1 3 +\dots +\frac 1 {3^{n-3}}$ and $2S_n:= \frac 2  {3^1}+\frac 2  {3^2}+\dots +\frac 2{3^{n-2}}$. $S_n=3S_n-2S_n=\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 9 + \frac 1 {27}+\dots +\left(\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}-\frac{2}{3^n}\right)$, but that would just be the series $\sum\limits _{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{k-2}}$. I'm not really sure how to determine the limit and that's why I would appreciate some help.

Comment: It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner could I just use the fact, that a geometric series converges at $\frac{1}{1-n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{k=3}^m\frac{1}{3^{k-2}}=\frac{1}{2} 3^{-m} \left(3^m-9\right)$$

Comment: Can you explain how you came to this equality?

Comment: It it a geometrical sum, this means $$\sum_{n=1}^k q^n=\frac{q \left(q^k-1\right)}{q-1}$$

Comment: Thank you!    ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{1}{3^{k-2}}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}$$

Then we have:

$$\begin{matrix}3S_n = &1&+&\frac{1}{3}&+&\frac{1}{3^2}&+&\cdots&+&\frac{1}{3^{n-3}}&\,\\
S_n=&\,&\,&\frac{1}{3}&+&\frac{1}{3^2}&+&\cdots&+&\frac{1}{3^{n-3}}&+&\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\end{matrix}$$

Subtracting, you get $$2S_n=3S_n-S_n= 1+0+0+\cdots+0-\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}=1-\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}$$

So $S_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits _{k=3}^{n} \frac{1}{3^{k-2}}$$ is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with first term $\dfrac13$, ratio $\dfrac13$, and final term $\left(\dfrac13\right)^{n-2}.$

Therefore, the sum is $\dfrac{\dfrac13-\left(\dfrac13\right)^{n-1}}{1-\dfrac13}$ and approaches $\dfrac12$ as $n\to\infty$.